# Siebel Open UI - Missing theme.js

Tags: siebel

This might fall under the product support category, so if it's off topic, let me know. There doesn't seem to be anywhere in SE or elsewhere online to ask questions for help in Siebel and Open UI

Anyways, I'm trying to do something simple and include a custom css file with Siebel Open UI. This is just for testing purposes so I can start twaeking the UI and see what can be done.

Most guides such as [this](http://www1.askmesiebel.com/2014/02/how-to-change-theme-in-openui/), [this](http://www.siebelhub.com/main/2013/01/siebel-open-ui-custom-themes.html), and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/config_open_ui/customizing_mobile23.html) mention editing the theme.js file located at `PUBLIC/_language_/_build_/SCRIPTS/siebel`.

---

Problem is, this file doesn't exist in my installation. The only theme.js file at all is located under `PUBLIC/_language_/webeditor/themes/theme.js`.
The contents of this are minified, and when I run it through a beautifier, it has nothing of the `siebelApp.ThemeManager.addTheme` that the tutorials talk about.

This instead starts with `CKEDITOR.themes.add('default', (function() {` which is similar, but I can't use it to follow the tutorials to add a theme and reference a css file.

---

I've tried every guide on this I can find through Google, but it always comes down to editing theme.js file to have Siebel include a custom css file. I've even tried creating my own theme.js file and putting it in `scripts/siebel/custom` and added that to the manifest, but no luck.

Is Siebel not installed correctly? I have Siebel Tools, Client, and a sample db. Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File theme.js was deprected starting from Siebel IP2014. Now to add a new custom theme you have to do following:

1. Create separate CSS file with your custom style
2. Put this file to `PUBLIC/_language_/files/custom` folder
3. Add this file to Siebel manifest:

   1. Navigate to Site Map > Administration - Application > Manifest Files
   2. Create new record with a path to your file (path should start from `files/custom/...`)
   3. Navigate to Site Map > Administration - Application > Manifest Expressions
   4. Create new record with expression `LookupName(OUI_THEME_SELECTION, Preference("Behavior", "DefaultTheme")) = "_YOUR_CUSTOM_THEME_NAME_"`
   5. Navigate to Site Map > Administration - Application > Manifest Administration
   6. Create new record in the UI Objects applet ([Type] = "Application"; [Usage Type] = "Theme", [Name] = "_YOUR_CUSTOM_THEME_NAME_")
   7. Create new record in the Object Expression applet with the expression you've created previosly. Level should be equal to 1.
   8. Create new record(s) in the Files applet. If you just extend vanilla Aurora theme with your custom CSS rules than you need to add both files here and sequence is important - first one should be files/theme-aurora.css and the second one is you custom CSS file. If you create CSS file from scratch (or just copy aurora file) than you just need to add only your CSS file.
4. Create new record in LOVs ([Type] = "OUI_THEME_SELECTION"; [Display Value] = "user friendly name of you theme"; [LIC] = "_YOUR_CUSTOM_THEME_NAME_"; [Parent LIC] = "NAVIGATION_TAB" or "NAVIGATION_TREE" or "NAVIGATION_SIDE")

Comment: Thanks. Is it just me then, or is the documentation at [http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/config_open_ui/config_open_uiTOC.html](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/config_open_ui/config_open_uiTOC.html) a bit out of date then?

Comment: Documentation you pointed to is actualy for IP2013 version, this can be determined by code "E14004" in URL. List of all bookshelfs for every Siebel version can be found here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/documentation/siebel-087898.html

Comment: Thanks so much - you've found so simple something a bunch of people on my team have missed with this. I won't be able to try this for about a week, but I'm marking this as correct for now.

Comment: Of course, though, all the links are dead on that page for me right now. I can google for them, at least

Comment: That is strange. It works for me just fine. E.g. I can open index page for IP2015 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63029_01/portalres/pages/docalpha_all.htm
But of course googling is much easier, but you have to be carefull with the versioning

Comment: Yeah, works for me if I change download to docs in the url. Whatever. Thanks again, huge help!